# OnItemClickLisener does not work

Tags: android, listview, button, onitemclicklistener, listitem

i am trying to make list view with clickable items, and every list_item must consist 2 clickable buttons.

But if i add buttons to item layout, iten click listener stops to work...

here is my item_layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:gravity="center">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">
        <com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView
            android:id="@+id/friends_new_photo_circularImageView"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/user_friends_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/user_friends_height"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            app:border="true"
            app:border_color="#EEEEEE"
            app:border_width="2dp"
            app:shadow="true"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/friends_new_online_status_imageview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/online_status"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/friends_new_photo_circularImageView"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/friends_new_photo_circularImageView"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/friends_new_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/friends_new_rating"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/stars"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:onClick="true"
            android:text="Add"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:onClick="true"
            android:text="Dismiss"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

here  is fragment layout (with listView):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview_friends"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/ListViewStyle"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and here is my fragment with onCreateView and onItemClickListener:

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_friends_listview, container, false);
        ButterKnife.inject(this, rootView);

        String[] mNames = {
                "Example 1",
                "Example 2"
        };

        mFriendsAdapter = new FriendsAdapter(getActivity(), null, 0);

        List<String> mList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(mNames));
        ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(),
                R.layout.list_item_friends_new,
                R.id.friends_new_name,
                mList
        );

        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        FriendsFragment.openCurrentUser(getActivity());
    }
```

So here is the question:

is it possible to make clickable listItems with clickable buttons?
and if its true, than how to do it? if it false - maybe you have some other solution?

Comment: what log shows when you click buttons?

Comment: now it gives en error because for this moment i have not initialize button click listeners.

Comment: @KaranMer, but my problem is not this. when i add some buttons to item_layout, onItemClickLisener does not work

Comment: Focusable views in focusable views are bad for implementation most of the time. Your buttons inside the list probably stealing the focus from the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found solution from here..but by deep clicking...

If any row item of list contains focusable or clickable view then `OnItemClickListener` won't work.

The row item must have a param like `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants".`

here you can see example, how your list item should look like

row_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:gravity="center_vertical" >

// your other widgets here

</LinearLayout>
```

or add these two lines for the inner views

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Comment: android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
- i need to add this in child_layout with buttons or in main layout of list_item?

Comment: Thanks!
this work! and how now properly implement on button click listener?

Comment: First remove attribute  android:onClick="true" for the button because its method name should not be java keyword.
Listener should be added in the getView method of ListAdapter class..

Comment: Here is an detail example of list view. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: @Kartheek, and last one, if you would be so kind :)
i am implemented button onClickLisener, but how to catch from witch list item this button was clicked?

Comment: Since button click listener is implemented in the getView() method of your adapter, you will have the position as an argument in the getView() method. You can use it as list item position.

Answer (score 0):

remove onclick attribute like bellow in your code...

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:onClick="true"//remove this
                android:text="Add"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:onClick="true" //remove this
                android:text="Dismiss"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

and write your adapter as

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActivity(),
            R.layout.list_item_friends_new,
            R.id.friends_new_name,
            mList
    ){

        View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //your action on button click
            }
        };

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.yourButtonID);
            button.setOnClickListener(listener);
            return view;
        }
    };
```