# OnItemClick listener not triggered

Tags: android, xml, gridview, imageview

I am using customized gird view. I am inflating layout  as belew

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FEFAFA"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_first"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/grid_image_first"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false" >
        </ImageView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_second"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/grid_text_desc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" >
        </TextView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/grid_text"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/productpricefirstlayout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="RS 200"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="#F21111" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/discprice"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="(50% off)"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" >
                </TextView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/disc_ammount"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="(Rs.400)"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" >
                </TextView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/shareproduct"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/share" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have set setOnItemClickListener for grid view

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Filter Selected Otpins",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
```

but "setOnItemClickListener" not triggering. As I have already written for image.

```
"android:clickable="false"
                android:focusable="false""
```

So where I need to write 
these two lines in my xml?

Comment: there is no grid view in the layout

Comment: Why you give your ImageView those properties: "android:clickable="false"   and  android:focusable="false" ? also, did you give that ImageView an onClickListener inside your adapter?

Comment: Hi blueware,  I have written those lines to focus on grid view, to remove focus from image view. I can put on click listener for  image view inside Adapter class but I don't want that one. I need on click listener  for grid view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If any row item of list contains focusable or clickable view then `OnItemClickListener` won't work.

The row item must have a param like `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants".`

here you can see example, how your list item should look like

```
row_item.xml

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:gravity="center_vertical" >

// your other widgets here

</LinearLayout>
```

or add these two lines for the inner views

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

got the solution from my previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30572368/onitemclicklisener-does-not-work?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: Hi Kartheek thanks, its half done for me. I tried the above code for every widget but it only working for lower part <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_second". What should i do for "<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relative_first". focusable and focusableIntouchMode not working on this widget. This is the major part of my layout.

Comment: what does that lower part mean?

Comment: This one <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/relative_second" lower part of lay out.

Comment: add focusable and focusableInTouchMode to the views(button and text view).

Comment: Kartheek still no luck image is blocking that on click :(.

Comment: only problem with the image. Other parts of grid view is working. If I remove image view ten its working.

Comment: have you added android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false" to the imageView

Comment: Kartheek android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" is right answer, but it was not working of android:background="@drawable/ic_action_refresh" this line in image view. I don't know why. When I removed that line and put android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" for parent lay out its working perfect. Thanks Kartheek.